# Is there a way to pass system environment variable set on docker container to Laravel-5.6 app

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-5, dockerfile, docker-container

Laravel has its own environment configuration file (.env) where all application configuration variables are declared.

If I am running a Laravel-5.6 in dockerfile based docker container and want to send number of system environment variables that is set on docker container (while creating it using `docker run`) , how can this be achieved ?

Comment: Not sure if there's a way to automatically handle that, but you could define copies in `.env`, like `DOCKER_...=whatever` as a fallback. Suppose that depends on how often the variable will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Dockerfile you can set ENV vars like :

```
# Environment Variables
ENV NAME World
```

Then anywhere in Laravel you should be able to access it like

```
 $name=env('NAME');
 dd($name); //should output "World"
```